How to generate minimal epub file using ebooklib
I would like to use python and ebooklib to generate a "minimal" epub from an existing one. In other words, I want to keep only the required subset of metadata (title, creator, date, publisher), cover image, toc, spine, and (obviously) the whole text, and remove all extra-stuff (extra metadata, extra images, fonts, and so on).
Here is my current code:
import ebooklib as ebl
from ebooklib import epub

def minimal_epub(filename):
  old, new = epub.read_epub(filename), epub.EpubBook()

  for key in ['title', 'creator', 'date', 'publisher']:
    metadata = old.get_metadata('DC', key)
    if metadata: new.add_metadata('DC', key, metadata[0][0])
    print(new.get_metadata('DC', key)) # show current metadata field

  print(new.metadata) # show all metadata fields
  
  # assume that the largest image in archive is the cover image 
  sortkey = lambda item: -len(item.content) # sort images by decreasing sizes
  cover = sorted(old.get_items_of_type(ebl.ITEM_IMAGE), key=sortkey)[0]
  new.set_cover(cover.file_name, cover.content) # keep largest image as cover
  print(cover.file_name) # show cover filename    

  for item in old.get_items_of_type(ebl.ITEM_DOCUMENT):
    new.add_item(item); print(item) # show name of document items

  for item in old.get_items_of_type(ebl.ITEM_STYLE):
    new.add_item(item); print(item) # show name of styles

  new.toc = old.toc; print(new.toc) # show links in table of content
  new.spine = old.spine; print(new.spine) # show spine
  
  new.add_item(epub.EpubNcx()); new.add_item(epub.EpubNav()) # navigation

  epub.write_epub(filename.replace('.','+.'), new)

>>> minimal_epub('path/to/file.epub')


I don't know how to find the cover image among all images stored in the epub file, so I assume that the one with largest size is the cover (the assumption works almost everytime).
The generated (minimal) epub file can be correctly opened with a standard epub reader about 8 times out of 10, but in the remaining cases, the reader complains about incorrect format and cannot correctly display the book. So I guess that some other items in the archive should also be copied, but I am not a specialist of the epub format, and the documentation of the ebooklib package is rather short and doesn't cover all details.
Is there an epub wizard here, to give me some hints?
